# NSOperationQueue Complete

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to make a queue request, But i was wondering if there is a way to know When the queue has finished With all the request here is part of my code

```
 for (int i=0; i< [result count]; i++) 
{
    Reportes *temp    =   [result objectAtIndex:i];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request     =   [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setTag:0];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERNAME] forKey:POST_USUARIO];
    [request setPostValue:[KeychainWrapper keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:PIN_SAVED] forKey:POST_CLAVE];
    [request setPostValue:POST_IDSISTEMA_VALUE forKey:POST_IDSISTEMA];
    [request setPostValue:[self getMacAddress] forKey:POST_MAC];

    [request setPostValue:[[temp toNSDictionary] JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"value"];
    [[self queue] addOperation:request];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the following method

```
- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
    // You could release the queue here if you wanted
    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setNetworkQueue:nil]; 
    }
    NSLog(@"Queue finished");
}
```

`queueFinished` is the one that gets called after all the requests have finished. In order for this to work you have to call

```
[[self queue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];
```

when you initialize the queue

Comment: of course you also have to set the delegate for the queue `[[self queue] setDelegate:self];`

Comment: is this methond setQueueDidFinishSelector on ASIHTTPRequest_? i cant find it

Comment: yes. You're probably using `NSOperationQueue`, but you may use a `ASINetworkQueue`instead. It's a subclass of the first one and it has the selector I told you about. It also lets you check the progress of the overall process. You add all the request to it and then you call `[queue go]`. When finished all requests, you'll get the call you wanted